# How to have abstract model with unique_together?

Tags: django, django-models

Why I am getting:

```
Error: One or more models did not validate:
test.test: "unique_together" refers to slug. This is not
in the same model as the unique_together statement.
test.test: "unique_together" refers to version. This is not
in the same model as the unique_together statement.
```

I have such model definition:

```
class SlugVersion(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        unique_together = (('slug', 'version'),)

    slug = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=10, editable=False)
    version = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, editable=False)

class Base(SlugVersion):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Test(Base):
    test = models.IntegerField()
```

I have Django 1.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is a [bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16732) in Django.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `Test` is inheriting from `Base` using [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), which creates separate tables for the two models and links them with a OneToOne relationship. So the `slug` and `version` fields exist only in the `Base` table but not in the Test table.

Do you need `Base` to be non-abstract? In other words, will you create any actual `Base` objects? If you set it to be abstract, this error goes away.

Comment: I want `slug` and `version` to be only in the `Base` table. And I want Django to make unique constraint there (on database level). And this is it. `Test` would then have 1-1 relationship with that table, now having that constraint itself.